# A finite abelian group minus an element which is its own inverse is closed.

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

This is a step in a proof I'm trying to do. Let G be a finite abelian group with $a_1,...,a_n$ its elements. If $a_n \neq e$, $a_n = a_n^{-1}$ and $a_i, a_j \in G \setminus \{a_n\}$, can I conclude that $a_ia_j \in  G \setminus \{a_n\}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_4$. $2$ is it's own inverse, but $1+1=2$ where $1\in \mathbb{Z}_4\setminus \{ 2\} $.  So I think the answer is no, unless there are more conditions.